# Arrange elements around circle in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement the UI similar to following in flutter. What I want to do is position some elements inside the circle 1,2,3,4 and so on. I want to position it such that they are not lined up but randomized on each of the 1,2,3,4 and so on circles. As of now I have stacked each of the circle from big to small to make this background. How can I position the elements such that it is at random angle in each of the circles?

[image]

Comment: use `CustomMultiChildLayout` some sample delegate is here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/50554a116698f03a862a356c38b75eb3#file-rotary_dial-dart-L114

Comment: Thank you for the help @pskink . I used custompainter to draw the background and stack with Transform.translate to place the widgets. I couldn't wrap my head around the above code but it sure gave me the idea.